# Adding object to array in array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested

I have this data structure (classes with comments) and I want to add a 1-level deep reply. This means that I'd like to add another object on a "comentarios" element.

How can I achieve this with mongo?
This means: Match cursada (db) id, match clase (first array) id, match comment (second array) id, then add a new element there.

```
db.cursada.find({"_id": ObjectId("55444f56e5e154f7638b456a")}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55444f56e5e154f7638b456a"),
        "clases" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "554e7f2fe5e154797d8b4578",
                        "titulo" : "qewewqewq"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "554e8be0e5e154dc698b4582",
                        "titulo" : "la mejor clase"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "554eb90de5e154dd698b458b",
                        "comentarios" : [
                                {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("55a021afe5e154cf098b4567"),
                                        "nombreUsuario" : "nombre",
                                        "texto" : "432432423"
                                }
                        ],
                        "titulo" : "Peeling - cosa"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "554e91a0e5e154797d8b4587",
                        "titulo" : "fdsfdsa"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "554f8f50e5e154dd698b458f",
                        "titulo" : "clase2"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "554f99dae5e154797d8b45a7",
                        "titulo" : "con profesor"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "554fa4a0e5e154797d8b45c4",
                        "titulo" : "profesor nombre nombre"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "5557b37be5e154e07f8b4567",
                        "titulo" : "Dermatologia I"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "5557c701e5e154066d8b456c",
                        "titulo" : "Acido hialuronico"
                }
        ],
        "curso" : "552fa5f1e5e1542e628b4567",
        "fechaFin" : "2015-05-22T03:00:00.000Z",
        "fechaIni" : "2015-05-08T03:00:00.000Z",
        "titulo" : "cremotas"
}
```

Getting this result:

```
  {
            "_id" : ObjectId("55444f56e5e154f7638b456a"),
            "clases" : [
                  {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("554eb90de5e154dd698b458b"),
                        "comentarios" : [
                                {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("55a021afe5e154cf098b4567"),
                                        "nombreUsuario" : "nombre",
                                        "texto" : "432432423",
                                        ----------------HERE
                                        "replies": [
                                        { "_id": ....,
                                        "user": ....,
                                        "text":....,
                                        "date":....
                                        }]
                                        ----------------HERE

                                }
                        ],
                        "titulo" : "Peeling - cosa"
                },
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One twisted example!

Luckily it presents no problem to MongoDB and its [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query operator:

```
Model.update({
  _id: "55444f56e5e154f7638b456a",
  classes: {
    $elemMatch: {
      _id: "554eb90de5e154dd698b458b",
    }
  }
}, {
  $push: {
    'classes.$.comentarios': {
       nombreUsuario: 'New comment nombreUsuario',
      texto: '111242515'
    }
  }
}, function(err, count) {
  console.log('Updated ' + count + ' document');
});
```

What happens here?

First, we're specyfing specific *course* (*"cursada"*) to update:

```
_id: "55444f56e5e154f7638b456a"
```

Then, using [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator, we're restricting result of the query to contain only one *class*:

```
  classes: {
    $elemMatch: {
      _id: "554eb90de5e154dd698b458b",
    }
  }
```

Now, having found specific *class* to update, we can finally add new *comment* to it. Here's our update query:

```
$push: {
  'classes.$.comentarios': {
    nombreUsuario: 'New comment nombreUsuario',
    texto: '111242515'
  }
}
```

1. [`$push` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) tells MongoDB to *add* new comment to specified array of comments.
2. `'classes.$.comentarios'` specifies which nested `comentarios` array to update, using [`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).
3. Finally, and this part should be self-explanatory: full object of new comment to add to the specified *class*.

It's also worth mentioning that if you're running into such deeply nested structure, perhaps it's worth thinking about spreading *courses*, *classes*, possibly even *comments* over separate MongoDB collections.

When nested documents are the way to go and when it's better to create separate collections can be actually tricky question to answer - here's [nice presentation](http://openmymind.net/Multiple-Collections-Versus-Embedded-Documents/) discussing this issue.

Comment: This is almost what I want; I want to go a level deeper and add an answer to the specific comment! The documents are arranged this way because: courses is a name+list of {class id, comments(for this class-course), various class-course data}. The class itself is on its own document. --- So to sum it up, I need to add a reply (text-name-date object) to a specific course->class->comment (where each is an element of an array [courses,classes,comments])

Comment: Sorry, I must've missed that - and it's quite a fundamental part of the question, oops! What you're talking about is actually long-standing (5 years) MongoDB feature request, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831 . Right now you could possibly only identify comment to reply to by its index in `comentarios` array, like so: `$push: { 'classes.$.comentarios.0.replies': { ... } }` (add reply to first comment of specified course). Does that satisfy you? - I can edit the answer to reflect that, but it's not *exactly* what you mean, I'm afraid.

Comment: Also keep in mind your emergency option - which always is to first retrieve the full document, then edit is as wanted, then save it (overwriting the old document).

Comment: Updating by index won't do, as I don't know the indexes to modify(and even if I stored them, upon deleting an item, I'd need to update the following items, and I'd be in the same spot that I'm now); I'll resort to the emergency option, thanks